# firebase auth cordova-ios stopped working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, firebase-authentication, google-plus

I have a cross-platform app using **Cordova** and **Firebase**.

Unfortunately Auth on iOS devises stopped working. Android works well, but iOS doesn’t.

Moreover old builds on TestFlight, which used to work now stopped login the user. I use `SingInWithRedirect`. I can enter email and password from Gmail account, but after that I don’t get redirected back to the app and don’t receive any object, error also doesn’t show.

I even created a plain app with auth only just like in documentation, but it doesn’t work anyway.

Here is my component:

```
start: function() {

    console.log('starts');

    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function() {
      return firebase.auth().getRedirectResult();
        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log('result', result);
          // This gives you a Google Access Token.
          // You can use it to access the Google API.
          var token = result.credential.accessToken;
          // The signed-in user info.
          var user = result.user;
          // ...
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('error', error);
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
    });
}
```

Here is my `config.xml`:

```
<widget id="com.gigover.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>HelloCordova</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<universal-links>
    <host name="d3988.app.goo.gl" scheme="https" />
    <host name="gigover2.firebaseapp.com" scheme="https">
        <path url="/__/auth/callback"/>
    </host>
</universal-links>
<content src="index.html" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-buildinfo" spec="~2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-universal-links-plugin" spec="~1.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-browsertab" spec="~0.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.7.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" spec="~4.3.0">
    <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="com.gigover.app" />
</plugin>
```

Comment: Did this change after you upgraded the Firebase version? or did it change after you updated one the plugins it depends on, like `cordova-plugin-customurlscheme`? Try detecting the incoming app link to make sure the issue is not in the plugin by adding a `function handleOpenURL(url) {console.log(url);}`Something must have changed. Try isolating that.

Comment: figured out what was wrong. URL_SCHEME and CFBundleURLTypes should have the same link in config.xml and ios.json inside cordova ios platform. By some reason in ios.json it was overwritten by default cordova link

Comment: Thanks for following up with the resolution for this issue.